# Tikz externalize + macro's ? Or how would you do it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, external-files, tikz-external

I'm currently building courses for some of my college teachers. The aim is to make their Word/MS paint generated study material into high grade Latex/Tikz material.

I'm aiming for high consistency in figures (expecially plots) and I've therefore written a bunch of macro's that generate tikz pictures for me from data I get form `Matlab` using the `matlab2tikz.m` code (which was written at my college!).

What I've done is write a bunch of "*set*" macro's that set a current variable to be something e.g. `\figxlabel{$x$-axis}` (see my code below) would set another macro `\thefigxlabel`to contain `$x$-axis`. All of this info is then used in the next `\matlabfig{data.tikz}`, after which it is reset to neutral values. Since everything is in macro's I don't need to remember what the special settings for a plot were, and even better I can change the `\matlabfig` macro to change all pictures at once!

But, then I discovered the Tikz `externalize` library which, since my documents are getting large (I split them up but still...), would come in very handy. Yet, this library doesn't support macro usage in tikzpictures.. What would you do to combine the best of two worlds?

I was thinking to use the macro's to set global tikz properties that apply to all figures (I don't know if i can do `\tikzset{every xlabel={$x$-axis}}`) and then change this between pictures, so it would only apply to the next one. This way there wouldn't be any macro's inside the tikz environment. I'd have to use a non-macro `\begin` and `\end` structure then I'm guessing.

All my written macro's are given in the next piece of code (these should work):

```
\def\figurewidth{7.5cm}
\def\figureheight{4cm}

\newcommand{\thefigtitle}[0]{\null}%title
\newcommand{\thefigtith}[0]{0cm}
\newcommand{\figtitle}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\thefigtitle}{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\thefigtith}{0.35cm}%
}

\def\figysep{1}

\newcommand{\thefigxlabel}[0]{\null}%xlabel
\newcommand{\thefigxh}[0]{0}

\newcommand{\figxlabel}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\thefigxlabel}{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\thefigxh}{-0.35}%
}

\newcommand{\thefigylabel}{}%ylabel
\newcommand{\figylabel}[1]{\renewcommand{\thefigylabel}{#1}}

\newcommand{\thefiglabel}{ }%label
\newcommand{\figlabel}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\thefiglabel}{\label{#1}}%
}  

\newcommand{\thefigxrange}[0]{ }%x-range
\newcommand{\figxrange}[2]{
    \renewcommand{\thefigxrange}{xmin=#1,xmax=#2,}
}  


\newcommand{\thefigyrange}[0]{ }%y-range
\newcommand{\figyrange}[2]{%
    \renewcommand{\thefigyrange}{ymin=#1,ymax=#2,}
}  

\newcommand{\thefiglegend}{ }%legend
\newcommand{\figlegend}[2]{%
    \renewcommand{\thefiglegend}{legend entries={#1},legend pos={#2}}%
}

\newcommand{\thefigcaption}{\caption{}}%caption
\newcommand{\figcaption}[1]{\renewcommand{\thefigcaption}[0]{\caption{#1}}}

\newcommand{\thefigextra}{ }%extra options
\newcommand{\figextra}[1]{\renewcommand{\thefigextra}[0]{#1}}

\newcommand{\thefigpos}{htp}
\newcommand{\figpos}[1]{\renewcommand{\thefigpos}[0]{#1}}

\newcommand{\matlabfig}[1]{%figuur zelf
    \begin{figure}[\thefigpos]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[]
            \draw[use as bounding box,draw=none](0,0+\thefigxh)rectangle(\figurewidth,\figureheight+\thefigtith);           
            \begin{axis}[%
            view={0}{90},
            scale only axis,
            width=\figurewidth,
            height=\figureheight,
            y tick label style={font={\tiny}}, 
            x tick label style={font={\tiny}}, 
            title={\textbf{\textsc{\thefigtitle}}},
            xlabel={\textbf{\thefigxlabel}},
            ylabel={\textbf{\thefigylabel}},
            \thefigxrange
            \thefigyrange
            axis on top,\thefiglegend,
            \thefigextra,
            minor tick num=1
            ]
                \input{#1}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \thefigcaption\thefiglabel
\end{figure}
%alles resetten 
\figreset}


\newcommand{\figreset}[0]{
\renewcommand{\thefigtitle}{ }%
\renewcommand{\thefigxlabel}{ }% 
\renewcommand{\thefigxh}{0}%
\renewcommand{\thefigtith}{0cm}% 
\renewcommand{\thefigylabel}{}% 
\renewcommand{\thefigcaption}{\caption{}}%
\renewcommand{\thefiglabel}{}%
\renewcommand{\thefiglegend}{}%
\renewcommand{\thefigxrange}{}%
\renewcommand{\thefigyrange}{}%
\renewcommand{\thefigextra}{ }%
\renewcommand{\thefigpos}{htp}%
}
```

**EDIT: added a working minimal example**

contents of `example.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\figurewidth{7.5cm}
\def\figureheight{4cm}

\newcommand{\thefigtitle}[0]{\null}%title
\newcommand{\thefigtith}[0]{0cm}
\newcommand{\figtitle}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\thefigtitle}{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\thefigtith}{0.45cm}%
}

\def\figysep{1}

\newcommand{\thefigxlabel}[0]{\null}%xlabel
\newcommand{\thefigxh}[0]{0}

\newcommand{\figxlabel}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\thefigxlabel}{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\thefigxh}{-0.35}%
}

\newcommand{\thefigylabel}{}%ylabel
\newcommand{\figylabel}[1]{\renewcommand{\thefigylabel}{#1}}

\newcommand{\thefiglabel}{ }%label
\newcommand{\figlabel}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\thefiglabel}{\label{#1}}%
}  

\newcommand{\thefigxrange}[0]{ }%x-range
\newcommand{\figxrange}[2]{
    \renewcommand{\thefigxrange}{xmin=#1,xmax=#2,}
}  


\newcommand{\thefigyrange}[0]{ }%y-range
\newcommand{\figyrange}[2]{%
    \renewcommand{\thefigyrange}{ymin=#1,ymax=#2,}
}  

\newcommand{\thefiglegend}{ }%legend
\newcommand{\figlegend}[2]{%
    \renewcommand{\thefiglegend}{legend entries={#1},legend pos={#2}}%
}

\newcommand{\thefigcaption}{\caption{}}%caption
\newcommand{\figcaption}[1]{\renewcommand{\thefigcaption}[0]{\caption{#1}}}

\newcommand{\thefigextra}{ }%extra options
\newcommand{\figextra}[1]{\renewcommand{\thefigextra}[0]{#1}}

\newcommand{\thefigpos}{htp}
\newcommand{\figpos}[1]{\renewcommand{\thefigpos}[0]{#1}}

\newcommand{\matlabfig}[1]{%figuur zelf
    \begin{figure}[\thefigpos]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[]
            \draw[use as bounding box,draw=none](0,0+\thefigxh)rectangle(\figurewidth,\figureheight+\thefigtith);            
            \begin{axis}[%
            view={0}{90},
            scale only axis,
            width=\figurewidth,
            height=\figureheight,
            y tick label style={font={\tiny}}, 
            x tick label style={font={\tiny}}, 
            title={\textbf{\textsc{\thefigtitle}}},
            xlabel={\textbf{\thefigxlabel}},
            ylabel={\textbf{\thefigylabel}},
            \thefigxrange
            \thefigyrange
            axis on top,\thefiglegend,
            \thefigextra,
            minor tick num=1
            ]
                \input{#1}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \thefigcaption\thefiglabel
\end{figure}
%alles resetten 
\figreset}


\newcommand{\figreset}[0]{
\renewcommand{\thefigtitle}{ }%
\renewcommand{\thefigxlabel}{ }% 
\renewcommand{\thefigxh}{0}%
\renewcommand{\thefigtith}{0cm}% 
\renewcommand{\thefigylabel}{}% 
\renewcommand{\thefigcaption}{\caption{}}%
\renewcommand{\thefiglabel}{}%
\renewcommand{\thefiglegend}{}%
\renewcommand{\thefigxrange}{}%
\renewcommand{\thefigyrange}{}%
\renewcommand{\thefigextra}{ }%
\renewcommand{\thefigpos}{htp}%
}


\pgfplotsset{
    every tick/.style={thin,color=black},
    every axis legend/.append style={nodes={right}},
    every axis legend/.append style={font=\tiny},
    compat=newest
}

\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\scriptsize]

\begin{document}

 %%
\figcaption{an example fig}
\figlabel{fig:example}
\figtitle{example}
\figxlabel{$x$ axis}
\figylabel{$y$ axis}
\figlegend{data.tikz}{north west}
\figxrange{0}{6}
\figyrange{0}{5}
\figextra{}
\matlabfig{data.tikz}
%%

%another fig, but as you can see all was resetted
\matlabfig{data.tikz} 


\end{document}
```

contents of `data.tikz`:

```
\addplot [
color=black,
solid
]
coordinates{(0,0) (3,3) (4,5) (5,4)};
```

---

### How to to it with environments?

The following example contains the most basic `newenvironment` to create a `tikzpicture`. What I'm actually going for has a bit more options, but the problem remains the same.

Here's a small piece of sample code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\newenvironment{mytikz}{%
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}}
{\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{figure}}

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{mytikz}
    \draw(0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{mytikz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MWE works just fine using the externalisation library.  Converting the syntax to use `pgfkeys` actually solves the scoping problem since keys are local to the current scope.  Thus you can pass the keys and values as an option to the `matlabfig` command and they will be used only internally to that command.

I'm only a newcomer to the world of of `pgfkeys` so there may be better ways of implementing this, but here's a conversion of your macros into `pgfkeys` language.  I only changed one thing in the input syntax: the ranges are specified as `x range=0:6` instead of `x range={0}{6}`.

When putting this in to an environment, the problem is that the externalisation library looks for `\end{tikzpicture}` **without** doing any expansion.  In an ordinary environment, this doesn't work because the `\end{tikzpicture}` is hidden behind a `\end{myenvironment}`.  So we have to have a method whereby the `\end{myenvironment}` is expanded *at the same time* as the `\begin{tikzpicture}`.  Fortunately such a method exists and is to use the [environ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package.  This makes environments behave a little like commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/force remake=true}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\figurewidth{7.5cm}
\def\figureheight{4cm}

\pgfkeys{/matlab plot/.cd,
  title/.default={\null},
  title height/.default={0cm},
  x label/.default={\null},
  x label height/.default={0},
  x range/.code args={#1:#2}{\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/x range}{xmin=#1,xmax=#2}},
  y range/.code args={#1:#2}{\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/y range}{ymin=#1,ymax=#2}},
  legend/.code args={#1#2}{\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/legend}{legend entries=#1,legend pos=#2}},
  title/.code={%
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/title}{#1}%
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/title height}{0.45cm}},
  x label/.code={%
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/x label}{#1}%
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/x label height}{-0.35}},
  caption/.code={%
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/caption}{\caption{#1}}},
  label/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/caption}{\label{#1}}}%
}

% Initialise
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/caption}{}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/label}{}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/x label}{}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/y label}{}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/extra}{}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/legend}{}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/x range}{}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/x range}{}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/y range}{}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/y range}{}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/matlab plot/pos}{}

\def\figysep{1}

\newcommand{\matlabfig}[2][]{%figuur zelf
  \begingroup
  \pgfkeys{/matlab plot/.cd,#1}
    \begin{figure}[\pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/pos}]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[]
%            \draw[use as bounding box,draw=none](0,0+\pgfkeysvalueof{x label height})rectangle(\figurewidth,\figureheight+\pgfkeysvalueof{title height});           
            \begin{axis}[%
            view={0}{90},
            scale only axis,
            width=\figurewidth,
            height=\figureheight,
            y tick label style={font={\tiny}}, 
            x tick label style={font={\tiny}}, 
            title={\textbf{\textsc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/title}}}},
            xlabel={\textbf{\pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/x label}}},
            ylabel={\textbf{\pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/y label}}},
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/x range},
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/y range},
            axis on top,
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/legend},
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/extra}
            minor tick num=1
            ]
                \input{#2}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/caption}
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/label}
\end{figure}
    \endgroup}

\NewEnviron{MatlabFig}[1][]{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfkeys{/matlab plot/.cd,#1}
  \begin{figure}[\pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/pos}]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
%            \draw[use as bounding box,draw=none](0,0+\pgfkeysvalueof{x label height})rectangle(\figurewidth,\figureheight+\pgfkeysvalueof{title height});           
            \begin{axis}[%
            view={0}{90},
            scale only axis,
            width=\figurewidth,
            height=\figureheight,
            y tick label style={font={\tiny}}, 
            x tick label style={font={\tiny}}, 
            title={\textbf{\textsc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/title}}}},
            xlabel={\textbf{\pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/x label}}},
            ylabel={\textbf{\pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/y label}}},
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/x range},
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/y range},
            axis on top,
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/legend},
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/extra}
            minor tick num=1
            ]
  \BODY
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/caption}
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/matlab plot/label}
\end{figure}
    \endgroup}

\pgfplotsset{
    every tick/.style={thin,color=black},
    every axis legend/.append style={nodes={right}},
    every axis legend/.append style={font=\tiny},
    compat=newest
}

\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\scriptsize]

\begin{document}

 %%
\matlabfig[
        caption=an example fig,
        label=fig:example,
        title=example,
        x label=$x$ axis,
        y label=$y$ axis,
        legend={data.tikz}{north west},
        x range=0:6,
        y range=0:5,
        ]{tikzextkeys_data.tikz}

%%

%another fig, but as you can see all was resetted
\matlabfig{tikzextkeys_data.tikz} 

\begin{MatlabFig}[
        caption=an example fig,
        label=fig:example,
        title=example,
        x label=$x$ axis,
        y label=$y$ axis,
        legend={data.tikz}{north west},
        x range=0:6,
        y range=0:5,
        ]
\input{tikzextkeys_data.tikz}
\end{MatlabFig}

\end{document}
```

(NB In this code, something is going wrong when I uncomment the bounding box line.  It's to do with getting the lengths and values of the keys to interact properly.)

Comment: I admit I hadn't tried using macro's in a non-macro'ed tikzpicture, because the problem is really how to add all my macro's to one figure every time without forgetting one? Could I set up one `pgfkey` that includes all these macro's at once?

Comment: @romeovs: Since the **entire** picture is in a macro, I don't think that there's any difficulty.  TeX expands the macro `\matlabfig` _first_, then TikZ notices that it is picture and tries to externalise it.  But as TeX has already expanded the `\matlabfig`, TikZ "sees" the picture just as if it were included in your document as-is.  (Could you add a sample data file to your question, otherwise I can't experiment with it.)

Comment: @romeovs: To be clear: I think that there are two questions here.  1) would this work with externalisation?  To which I think that the answer is "Yes", but you should really just try it and see. 2) how could this be done using `pgfkeys`?  To which the answer is: make sure that they keys are set and used in the same grouping, then there's no need to reset things.  To add to my request for sample data, please also add a sample of usage: namely, how you'd normally set all these values.

Comment: ok,added an example

Comment: @romeovs: Okay, I've had a go at converting that to use `pgfkeys`.  As I said, I think that the externalisation library works just fine with it as it is, (note that it's in my example just to show that).  Using the keys makes the command a lot cleaner, I think, so it's worth doing even without the issues about externalisation.

Comment: yes as you said.. It does seem to work: it just didn't with the file I was already working on (don't know why, but doesn't matter, I was asking this question for future reference anyways). I'll check your approach (and probably accept!).

Comment: You're code doesn't seem to work as intended ( I get strange pictures, without labels etc..), but it's a good start for me to get working on my own..

Comment: It seems the use of the bounding box explains why there are no axis labels etc.. Everything is cut off (as if `clip` were used) when it is externalized..

Comment: @romeovs: Yes, I noticed that!  I meant to say something but then forgot (as I noticed it before doing the pgfkeys stuff).  Sorry.  If you comment out the bounding box, does it do what you expect?  If there's a specific reason why you want the bounding box, that might be worth asking in a new question how to achieve it.

Comment: yes, I will be doing that. I like the way the use of a `bounding box` that fits exactly around the width of the plotting area brings more balanca to a page. Especially in combination with a caption width (using the `caption` package) that is the same as `figurewidth`. This way the yticks or ylabel don't push the figure aside when `\centering` is used. You should try it to see the effect.

Comment: @romeovs: I can see the benefits of what you describe.  The problem is that the bounding box gets used in two different ways: one is to crop the resulting pdf to be as small as possible and the other is to say how big the box should be when it is re-included.  I don't know if it is possible to separate out those two, and I suggest asking a new question about it.

Comment: Would this still work for `\newenvironment`? It looks cleaner making a new environment that takes in `\addplot` and the eventul `\input{data.tikz}`.

Comment: @romeovs: I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Andrew: I can't get that to work though, I'm getting: `! File ended while scanning use of \tikzexternal@laTeX@collect@until@end@tikzpi
cture.`errors...

Comment: @romeovs: Can you edit your attempt at putting it in to an environment in to the question?  I think I know why that's happening, but seeing your attempt will confirm it and also clarify what you want from such an environment.

Comment: @Andrew: The question was edited

Comment: @romeovs: The answer has now been edited to match.

Comment: Ok, the newenviron package seems to work fine for environments that don't take extra options.. The problem is now that I was defining an environment that takes 2 optional arguments, usng the `xargs`package. I'd like to have a command `\begin{mytikz}[caption=mycaption][xscale=2]` that parses the first optional argument for use in the homebrew `pgfkeys` and puts the second optional argument in the `tikzpicture` optional arguments. I got this to work using the `xargs`package, but that didn't work (got the error I described). The `NewEnviron` doesn't allow for multiple optional arguments though.

Comment: @romeovs: You really are asking for it all, aren't you!  Why not use `pgfkeys` to do that?  Define a new key which gets put in the `tikzpicture` environment, so you'd specify it as `\begin{mytikz}[caption=mycaption,tikzargs={all the tikz arguments}]`.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking into that right now.. I didn't expect you to answer all these questions, you just did!! Thanks for helping me this much!

Comment: Isn't there another way to help the environment to expand on time (when `external`is looking for it)?

Comment: @romeovs: If there is, I don't know how to do it.  There are a couple of other environments that have the same basic issue: the `frame` environment from `beamer` and the `verbatim` environment.  There are quite a few answers about those scattered around this site, take a look at those for further ideas.